# Twitterizer Search

Tags: c#, search, twitter, twitterizer

We are new to Twitter Api / Twitterizer.

We have used the twitter search and then edited the URL as per the Twitter help and everything is fine ( http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=manchester%20airport%20delay ).

What we would like to do now is apply the same search using Twitterizer in our C# code.

Could anyone point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Searches with Twitterizer are pretty straight forward, since no authorization is required (or even accepted).

Here is a code sample to perform the search you linked to and looping through the results.

```cs
TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> searchResponse = TwitterSearch.Search("manchester airport delay");

// You should check that the request was successfull. If not, log/display/handle it.
if (searchResponse.Result != RequestResult.Success)
{
    // An example method call
    LogAndDisplayError(searchResponse.ErrorMessage);
}
else
{
    // The ResponseObject property will be a TwitterSearchResultCollection
    // You can bind many controls' datasource directly to the ResponseObject
    foreach (TwitterSearchResult result in searchResponse.ResponseObject)
    {
        // Which means each result will be a TwitterSearchResult
        DisplayResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: When running the code above I get this error:Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not cast or convert from System.Double to Twitterizer.TwitterSearchResultCollection.

Comment: I believe that bug has been corrected. Can you get the latest code from github and try again? If it continues, please report this as a new bug.

Comment: Hi Ricky,
The bug seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building it yourself, you may want to take a look at the LINQ to Twitter project at http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: He wasn't planning on building it himself, he was going to use a library, like Linq2Twitter. Your answer doesn't seem particularly helpful.